# How can I re-assemble list after using aggregate and $unwind in mongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm building an aggregate pipeline as follows

```
pipeline = [ 
        {"$unwind": "$categories"}
    ]
if len(cat_comp) > 0:
        pipeline.append({"$match": {"categories": {"$in": cat_comp}}})

result = mongo.db.xxx.aggregate(pipeline)['result']
```

The question is, how on performing the aggregation can I re-assemble the list of categories back in the results, because each record returned is the categories field corresponds to one of the items in the list. How can I rebuild the results such that I can perform the matching (`$match`) against a list of possibilities but recover the original list of categories.

It has been suggested that I try:

```
pipeline.append({"$group": {"categories": {"$push": "$categories"}}})
```

which I have modified to:

```
pipeline.append({"$group": {"_id": "anything", "categories": {"$push": "$categories"}}})
```

However now, I only get one record back which has for categories a massive list from all results. So what I would like to do is to take a document as thus:

```
{
"_id": 45666
"categories": ['Fiction', 'Biography']
"other": "sss"
}
```

and search from a user list `category_list = ['Anything', ...]` by passing through regular expressions as this:

```
cat_comp = [re.compile(cat, re.IGNORECASE) for cat in cat_list]
```

In the end, what is happening with aggregate(pipeline) is that I am losing "categories" as a list because of the `$unwind`. Now, how can I perform the query over the input data but return records that match where I have category as a list.

I'm also trying:

```
pipeline.append({"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "categories": { "$addToSet": "$categories" } } })
```

Which usefully returns a list of records with categories in a list - however, how can I see the rest of the record, I can only see `_id` and `categories`.

Comment: I've edited my answer below. You need to explicitly include all the fields you want in a `$group` document and can use the `$first` operator to collect repeated fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) step in the pipeline with a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to re-build the lists:

```
pipeline.append({"$group": {"categories": {"$push": "$categories"},"_id":"$_id","other": {"$first":"$other"}}})
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the following issue  {'$group': {'categories': {'$push': '$categories'}}}])]) on namespace heroku_xxx.$cmd failed: exception: a group specification must include an _id

Comment: I edited to the answer to include the `_id` field, you will need to explicitly include all the other fields that you want in the final document as well. The `$first` operator is useful when you have repeat values in the unwound documents.   As ever, spending the time to read through [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) is worth it.